# What should I pick first ASP.NET or PHP?

Tags: php, .net

I will roll up my sleeves and stop asking mulitple questions and start coding. I want to learn ASP.NET and PHP. Which one do you recommened me to start with and why?

I have taste of the two of them and have worked with them but just a little.

Thank you.

Comment: Toss a coin. Heads = ASP.net; Tails = PHP. Get started.

Comment: None is better than the other. This is a subjective, localized question and better resolved by examining the career opportunities in your area. Have you checked your local job ads lately?

Comment: Start with PHP - it's simpler and easier to get started with. You can easily get a site up and running and put PHP right in your pages, and more hosts support PHP hosting.

Comment: Goma: You have this site **completely backwards**; you should *not* have been asking questions yet, and you *should* be asking questions once you are actually coding, and have specific problems that you need concrete answers to.

Answer (score 5):

As a .Net developer, I think you should learn PHP first.

PHP requires a lot more manual effort in terms of code maintenance and structure, and requires you to think harder about security and basic OO principles.  ASP.Net abstracts a lot of stuff away for you and, while that's in many ways a good thing, may teach (or at least permit) a few lazy habits.

This question is by its very nature going to light up the religious zealotry in every developer, so maybe figure out which language you think you'll use most.  Decide whether you're likely to spend more time writing for open-source projects or hosting on Apache-based servers.  Are the people you're going to talk to most PHP or .Net?  Maybe it would be easier to learn from people who share the same language skills.

If you can get a good grasp of both, you'll certainly be very marketable.  Good luck to you.

Comment: I would second that, and add that you might want to start with a PHP MVC framework like CodeIgniter or Kohana, which enforce good OO coding practices and DRY principles.